# I want to hardcode numbers into an ActionListener without using the actual variable

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            visBoard[i][j] = new JButton();
            visBoard[i][j].addActionListener(e -> playTurn(i, j));
            moveSltPnl.add(visBoard[i][j]);
        }
}
```

Basically, I want to make the actionListener use the value of the variable, but not the actual variable itself

Comment: Assign it to a `final` variable before: `final int i2 = i; final int j2 = j`, and then use `i2` and `j2` in the lambda.

Comment: I know this is being picky, but instead of doing this `visBoard[i][j].addActionListener(...)` to make you code more readable, you should create the `JButton` variable and then use it to set its attributes. For example, `JButton tempButton = new JButton();` and then `tempButton.addActionListener(...);`. Lastly, `visBoard[i][j] = tempButton;`